# How to reproduce a "realistic" VPS hosting in a development environment

Tags: vps

I'd like to get more confident with linux and VPS management, as of now I've mostly used linux in shared hosting (in the few cases where SSH was enabled, else my only interface was cPanel).
Since I usually work on windows machines, I wanted to test out with Virtualbox, but was wondering what would be the most similar reproduction of a generic hosted VPS: running a flat distro in VB (was thinking Debian) or a Vagrant prebuilt image?

I've already used Vagrant few times but was quite discouraged by the very poor performance I've experienced, so I was wondering if a flat distro image would be more performant due to possible overhead that Vagrant could cause on top of VB.

I'd like to use this only for development and testing, not as an actual production environment.

Comment: What sort of performance issues did you have with Vagrant? Were you using shared folders? Don't forget to adjust the cores & RAM of your VM to something appropriate

Comment: @TimFountain I experienced very slow SSH session and general sluggish performance for the web server browsing the hosted websites / apps. Yes folders were shared between host and VM. AFAIK resources where adequate, though my machine is not very high on specs tbh.  
Just to clarify I'm not against the use of Vagrant at all, I'm just asking for more insights on this matter.